# Is there a tikkun to say/do when your relationship is in danger?

Tags: tefilla, marriage, divorce, mysticism-kabbalah

Has anyone come across a tikkun for a spouse during a separation?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for bringing your question here. By "tikkun" do you mean a prayer? Does the word mean some specific kind of prayer, or prayer in general? (To me the word conjures up images of herring and _ayer kichel_ offered on a yahrzeit, but I doubt that's what you mean. `:-)` ) If you could [edit] your question to clarify your intent, you'll more likely get answers that address your concern. See also http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1715.

Comment: Go to counseling?

Comment: You might be able to find something in Sefer Abia Tefilot from Machon Ish Masliah.

Comment: G-d forbid this situation should happen to anyone

Answer (score 1):

Repentance, Prayer, Charity and Forgiveness can do a lot.

Practically R. Arush's books "Garden of Emuna" and "Garden of Peace" speak a lot about it. May be also in "Womens' Wisdom".

Author writes explicit in very strong words, that "Garden of Peace" is intended for men only
and "Womens' Wisdom" is intended for women only.

Excepts from the books can be found on the website http://breslev.co.il.

Comment: from the wikipedia looks like the garden of peace is the same as women's wisdom... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shalom_Arush

Comment: as far as I understand "Women's wisdom" is book "Garden of peace" for women, what means both books have same topic and goal, but written for separate groups of people. As I heard someone - in field of education it's impossible to write a good book, that can address both groups of teachers and students. Reasonably teachers should read their books and students theirs.